# Template Class functions

Tags: c++, function, class, templates

Noobie programmer here, just learning class templates for c++.

My current project requires me to make a template class that can take ints, doubles, or strings as parameters.

So far, every time I have created the implementation of the class functions, i have to make 3 of each function (one for each parameter type).

My question is, if the implementation of a particular class function is exactly the same regardless of the parameter type, is there a way to just write one implementation for it?

Thanks in advance to all replies!

Comment: Yes, using templates...

Comment: That's the core reason for the existence of template. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max.

Comment: I closed as a dupe since it became clear from comments that the actual problem was getting linker errors when attempting to separate implementation from interface.

Answer (score 0):

This question is slightly unclear - first you say that the class template takes different parameters, but then it sounds like your member functions are taking these different parameters instead.

If your template class looks like

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    X(const T& t) : m_t(t) {}
    void print();
private:
    T m_t;
};
```

Your implementation of `print` could look like this:

```
template<typename T>
void X<T>::print() 
{ 
    std::cout << m_t; 
}
```

A member function can also be a template:

```
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    X(const T& t) : m_t(t) {}

    template<typename U>
    void printBefore(const U& u);
private:
    T m_t;
};
```

The definition of a function template within a class template looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename U>
void X<T>::printBefore(const U& u) 
{ 
    std::cout << m_t << u; 
}
```

Comment: sorry if my question was unclear. My problem has mostly been linker errors when I attempt to separate the implementation from the interface of the template class. I even tried it the way you wrote it on your reply but still linker error.

Comment: @user5540318 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file.

Comment: @user5540318 Why didn't you ask about your actual problem? I'm going to close this question as a duplicate.